# Custom Source Name for Datadog

Tags: datadog

How can I post my datadog events under custom source name?

I am trying to post a datadog event using following code.
Here source name is - **user**.

```
            EventCreateRequest body =
                new EventCreateRequest()
                        .sourceTypeName("user")
                        .title("Title")
                        .tags(tagList);
```

and it is showing up in Datadog events under user source
[image]

As available in above screenshot, there are various source names available such as - Kubernetes, watchdog, user, my_apps, Datadog.

How can I post an event under my custom source name.
For example, If I am posting event under source name - **custom**

```
            EventCreateRequest body =
                new EventCreateRequest()
                        .sourceTypeName("custom")
                        .title("Title")
                        .tags(tagList);
```

It goes under my_apps rather then a new custom tag.
[image]

I don't see a way to add a custom tag as well in Datadog UI.

Edit 1:
I found List of possible tags in following link, But still couldn't get a way to get custom source name.
https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/faq/list-of-api-source-attribute-value/

Answer (score 0):

Event sources are predefined on Datadog, every custom event source goes to "My Apps". I recommend using a custom tag for filtering this event

Comment: Thanks a lot @GondyB for answering.
Unfortunately, project requirement is such that I need custom event source.

Comment: Could you describe your use-case? Maybe I can help you find another way

Comment: Just want to have a source name - Production in the list

As

Kubernetes, Watchdog, users, my apps, datadog, Production

With code like:

EventCreateRequest body =
                new EventCreateRequest()
                        .sourceTypeName("Production")
                        .title("Title")